# Looping through all layers in Esri feature server

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

Because multiple layers aren't handled by the ESRIJSON driver. I have to query layer per layer. [source](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/4613)

I need to loop through all my feature layers, To generate a  GeoPackage file containing all layers.
I tried this :

```
ogr2ogr -skipfailures  -f  GPKG floridaData.gpkg "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services/COVID19Surge_Florida_InterventionScenarios/FeatureServer/0/query?where=OBJECTID+%3C1000&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outSR=4362&returnGeometry=true&sqlFormat=standard&f=json&maxRecordCountFactor=30&outFields=*&returnExceededLimitFeatures=false&resultType=tile" -nln 0

ogr2ogr -skipfailures -update floridaData.gpkg "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services/COVID19Surge_Florida_InterventionScenarios/FeatureServer/1/query?where=OBJECTID+%3C1000&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outSR=4362&returnGeometry=true&sqlFormat=standard&f=json&maxRecordCountFactor=30&outFields=*&returnExceededLimitFeatures=false&resultType=tile" -nln 1
```

It's working perfectly, but how I can generate the GeoPackage file dynamically using some kind of loop?

Do I need python to write the code or directly into the Terminal?